# Cannot set host to Android AVD

Tags: android, linux, localhost, root, android-virtual-device

I am working on linux machine. I want to change the hosts of my virtual device. so I want to edit **/etc/hosts**. by default android avd is rooted. but I can't remount the filesystem and unable to push file in /etc. showing **permission denied** and **Read only file system** errors. my console is given below

```
pranav@qburst:~$ adb root
adbd is already running as root
pranav@qburst:~$ adb remount
remount failed: Permission denied
pranav@qburst:~$ adb push hosts /system/etc/hosts
failed to copy 'hosts' to '/system/etc/hosts': Read-only file system
```

I tried adb shell command to remount the system but no use.